# how to validate date field on sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, ootb

I need to validate a date field. Consider, Date1 field will be empty initially. When user enter any date it should be future date. When I tried with Column Validation - it validates at empty state too.. How can I do this?

```
=[Date1]>Today()
```

Comment: paste the Formulas you tried

Comment: @DannyEngelman pls check the updated question again

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
=AND(   NOT(ISBLANK([Date1]))   ,   [Date1]>Today()   )
```

When you say "it validates at empty state too", do you mean you want it to accept an empty date?

Then use

```
=OR(   ISBLANK([Date1])   ,   [Date1]>Today()   )
```

Comment: its Not Working